# Probability of removing all the m red balls from a sack of n balls after p trials?

Tags: probability

I have a sack of $n$ balls, with $m$ red balls and $n-m$ blue balls $(n>m)$. I want to remove the red balls from the sack, so I randomly remove a ball from the sack, and check it's color. If the ball is red, I set it aside. If the ball is blue, I put it back into the sack. I repeat this process $p$ times.

What is the probability that I remove the $m^{th}$ red ball from the sack during the $p^{th}$ trial?

Edit: The only approach I can think of to solve this problem is to write it in terms of a recursive sum, ie., writing the probability of removing the $m^{th}$ red ball in the $p^{th}$ trial in terms of the probability of removing the $m-1^{th}$ red ball in the $p-1^{th}$ trial, and so on. However, the summation becomes real large and I don't see any simple way to reduce it into a closed form or easy to evaluate summation.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: This forum requires that you show the effort you have made, and where you are stuck before appropriate help is rendered. Pl edit it in , in the body of the question

Comment: I have edited the question to address the comments.